# Setting drawable to layout background results in null object reference error

Tags: android

I am trying to convert an `URI` into a `bit map` into a `drawable`:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(List.get(0).imageURI); 
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
```

I then set the drawable as the background of a layout:

```
layoutObject.setBackground(drawable);
```

However, setting the background to the drawable yields this error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method
'void android.widget.LinearLayout.
setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)'
on a null object reference
```

Comment: either layoutObject isn't defined or drawable has null value. First check if either of them is null before setting background.

Comment: @Sharj Sorry about that. You're absolutely right. If you want to copy and paste your comment as an answer, I can check mark it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

either `layoutObject` isn't defined or `drawable` has `null` value. First check if either of them is not `null` before setting `background`.